# Возможно ли изменить шрифт у FormulaControl? (WpfMath)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Я пишу приложение на WPF (NET Framework).

Код создания контрола:

```cs
xmlns:wpfMath="clr-namespace:WpfMath.Controls;assembly=WpfMath"
        
...
        
<wpfMath:FormulaControl x:Name="formulaControl" Scale="40" Foreground="White" Formula="ax+bx^2+c=0"
                                         SelectionBrush="LightBlue"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="148,35,331,279" Grid.Row="1" />
```

P.S. Я также пытался изменить стандартный `FontFamily`, но это также не приводило к каким-либо визуальным изменениям.

Возможно ли поменять стандартный шрифт у "FormulaControl" из библиотеки WpfMath?

Comment: Загуглилось это https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math/blob/master/docs/prepare-font.md

Comment: Мне кажется, это не совсем то что мне надо; есть ли другие способы?

Comment: А мне кажется, этот вопрос надо задавать автору конкретного проекта, а не сторонним людям, где большинство видят эту библиотеку впервые и будут также как и вы, гуглить информацию. У автора вон есть GitHub, напишите там, посмотрите что скажут.